# AngularJS - Tengo la siguiente estructura como llego a la tabla de abajo

Tags: angularjs

Tengo la siguiente estructura como llego a la tabla de abajo es importante que todos sean `td`

```
p:{
    0 :{
        s:{
        0 :{fruta:"manzana"}
        1 :{fruta:"pera"}
        }
    }
    1: {
        s: {
        0 :{fruta:"mango"}
        1 :{fruta:"uva"}
        }
    }
}
```

asi:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>manzana</td>
        <td>pera</td>
        <td>mango</td>
        <td>uva</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Brother, necesitamos más datos...
Estás utilizando angular o angularjs.. obtienes esos datos de un get request... o los tienes asignados a una variable?

Comment: Amigo con Angular js

Comment: Es un ejemplo similr de la estructura de un JSON , yo lo intente con ng repeat de p en tr y un ng repeat de s in p en td pero el resultado da 4  tr y lo nesecito como el de arriba

Comment: Por favor, postea tu código con el ng-repeat, y el controller de Angular, y también la parte donde obtienes los datos. Así será fácil poder ayudarte. Ya que lo

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/8kXimhIsvgjCuS22RLRe?p=preview

Comment: @Juana Hola buen día Juana por favor puedes colocar una estructura JSON valida para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

ya que lo subiste a plunker pude entender lo que quieres.

Tienes que tomar en cuenta que tu resultado quieres mostrarlo en una sola columna, entonces el último ng-repeat debería estar en el `<tr>` y no en el `<td>`

Puedes utilizar la etiqueta `<tbody>` por ejemplo para agruparlos.

Al final te quedaría algo así

```
<tbody ng-repeat="p in elementos">
      <tr ng-repeat="s in  p.Websites">
        <td >{{s.WebsiteName}}</td>
      </tr>
</tbody>
```

Espero te sirva

Comment: Muchas gracias Hugo, pero en realidad lo necesito en una misma fila

Comment: asi seria en angular 2 : <table border="1">
   <tr >
   <td *ngFor="let person of elementos; let i = index" border="1"> 
     {{person.Websites[1].WebsiteName}}
   </td>   
   </tr>
</table> pero yo lo nesecito en angularjs